# Is a Booking System where User and Participant are Different Entities Correct?

Tags: database-design, application-design

### Background

I am building a event booking system for a youth organisation. The events that can be booked are targeted in general at children under the age of 18 (i.e. which in Europe means that you especially need the approval of a legal guardian), but are not limited to them, as there are also events that can accept participants of all ages.

### Personas

Types of people this application could be:

1. Parents (**P**) - parents or legal guardians that want to sign-up their child to an event.
2. Underage participants (**UP**) - participants that view our events and would like to sign-up for them. Given that they are underage we require to contact their parent or legal guardian.
3. Participants of age (**OP**) - participants that don't require any permission from another person, and can freely sign-up to our events.

This is informal and used only to better explain the types of users that could use the website.

### Requirements

1. If a parent makes the booking from his user account, he'll have to enter his child's details.
2. If a child makes the booking from his user account, he'll have to enter the parents email address for him to sign him up.
3. If a participant of legal age makes the booking from his account, there is no requirement for the contact details of a legal guardian.
4. Children don't always have email addresses.
5. I don't require any other information from the child to uniquely identify him.
6. The application uses Django, so I need a **USER** table that handles the authentication. For this table the email is a required primary key.

### Setup

I came up with the following setup.

**USER** TABLE

- email - **CHAR PK REQUIRED**
- password - **CHAR REQUIRED**

**USER_PROFILE** Table

- user_id  - **FK on USER REQUIRED**
- phone - **CHAR REQUIRED**
- name - **CHAR REQUIRED**
- surname - **CHAR REQUIRED**
- dob - **DATE REQUIRED**

**PARTICIPANT** Table

- id - **UUID PK REQUIRED AUTO**
- supervised_by - **FK on USER REQUIRED**
- email - **CHAR**
- phone - **CHAR**
- medical_conditions - **CHAR**
- medications_to_take - **CHAR**

**EVENT** Table

- Event specific information not relevant for the scope of this question

**BOOKING** Table

- account_booking - **FK on USER REQUIRED**
- participant - **FK on PARTICIPANT REQUIRED**
- event_id - **FK on EVENT REQUIRED**

### Remarks

- the **USER** Table is used first and foremost as authentication
- the **USER_PROFILE** Table extends the **USER** Table with contact information

Now a user of our site, which can be either **P, UP, OP** wants to make a booking for an event. If he's:

- a **P** the web form will direct him to enter also the contact information of his child.
- a **UP** which wants to make a booking for himself, will be required to share his booking with his parent, for him to sign him up.
- a **OP** which wants to make a booking for himself, then the application will check his dob and based of it allow his sign-up.

### Problem

I have the above setup and I see the following problems with it:

1. For the case of the **OP** making a booking, I duplicate data in the **USER_PROFILE** Table as well as in the **PARTICIPANT** Table.
2. Participants that are now **UP** but could later be **OP** have duplicated information, similarly to the previous point.
3. I am not really sure this is the best setup, as I fell there could be a simpler, more elegant solution.

Comment: all NF evaluations are based on prime attributes / candidate keys. You haven't specified which attributes are prime and which are not, so it is impossible to evaluate NF compliance. I can only guess that email will be your user key, but then it doesn't make sense for contact details in which email is not required, and has no FK.

Comment: It looks like you are using NAME, SURNAME and DOB as the identifier of a user ? That seems problematic to me, since a user can change part of his/her details (choose to use a different first name, change family name ...). I think it is better to generate some unique user identity and use that.

Comment: Then it is not clear what relationship exists between users and contact details. Can there be multiple contact details for the same user ? And why is the email in the two tables ?

Comment: And your description talks about accounts and customers but your design does not mention any of those. You also talk about different kinds of users (P, UP, OP) but that is not mentioned anywhere either

Comment: I think email is the PK of user, as the other fields are optional. it seems that name and surname are not needed on user at all.